# IPSec point to point Cisco 2800 to Palo Alto firewall

Tags: routing, point-to-point

Is there a way to use a cisco 2800 router to create a point-point tunnel to a Palo alto 3020 firewall with support for 6 vlan's on the cisco side.  I want to create a tunnel from a new office to my HQ and I need to support VLAN's for management, phones, pc's, access points, printers, and servers all on different vlan's and subnets.

Comment: You really do not want layer-2 VLANs across the tunnel. That leads to all sorts of problems, and you propagate layer-2 problems between sites. Simply route between the sites through the tunnel, which then looks like a physical link between the routers.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to use a cisco 2800 router to create a point-point tunnel to a Palo alto 3020 firewall

Yes, IPsec is generally supported. You'll need to find a common parameter set though.

> with support for 6 vlan's on the cisco side.

Simply route into and out of the tunnel and use firewall rules to permit what you need and deny what you don't, e.g. 'permit VOIP-A to VOIP-B'.

On each router's LAN side you create/use VLANs to separate traffic on the L2 infrastructure. You neither need nor want VLANs on the VPN link.